# async rednering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

i have a problem where one of my components has to await to get some data while its rendering but i can't find a way to do that.

so i have the render method

```
render() {
    const getComponentProps = async () => {
                return await this.props.Store.getComponentProperties(id);
            };
    componentProps = getComponentProps(id);

    return <MyComponent
        .
        .
        data={componentProps}/>;
}
```

the problem is that my component is rendering before the data is fetched. i can't make the whole render await, i also tried making the componentProps a state on the hope it would rerender once it's ready, but that also didn't work. and finally i tried the new Suspense/Lazy feature in the new react version, which also didn't work.
the data i'm fetching is making a REST call to my database and I have to await it. also, the render it mapping over a list of components not just one, and for each component is has to get its properties and load them.

any thoughts on how to make this async data fetch in render ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this, you will have to use your `state`.
When your component is mounted, you can call the function `setState` and wait for your data to be fetched. Once the data is fetched, your component will re-render with the correct data :

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: null
        }
    }

    componentDidMount = async() => {
        this.setState({ data: await this.props.Store.getComponentProperties(id) })
    }

    render() {
        return <MyComponent2 data={this.state.data} />;
    }
}
```

If you do not want your child component to receive empty data, you can choose to not render it while your data has not been fetched :

```
render() {
    return this.state.data ? <MyComponent data={this.state.data} /> : <div/>
}
```

Comment: that worked!!! ... i modified a few things but your solution works.
thank you so much.